# How to tell if my AWS EC2 instance is Amazon-EBS backed?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Amazon EC2 instance (ubuntu) that I would like to resize to a larger size, but I don't want to have to rebuild the instance.  I've been told if it's EBS-backed, then I don't have to rebuild and I can just stop the instance and resize.

Some other info:

I have added an IAM role from s3 to this instance.

This instance is using t2.Micro

"Root device type" is EBS.

Two questions:

1) Can I resize this without having to rebuild the instance?
2) Would something like t3 medium work?  I'm seeing that's compatible with EBS based instances.

I'm estimating I'll have about 10 python scripts running simultaneously on this instance that are going to be using selenium for webscraping.

Comment: How to check programmatically? Both t2 and t3 are EBS-backed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the 1st question is Yes, you can safely resize the instance. 
AWS EC2 Root volume can be either an Instance Store Volume or an EBS Volume. If it is an EBS volume you don't have to worry about loosing data when starting/stopping the instance. If you look at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ you can see that t2.micro is "EBS-Only" which mean you cannot attach a Instance Store Volume even if you wanted to.

Answer to the 2nd question is not so straight forward since it depends on how your scripts work. So the best option would be to run them on a bigger instance and monitor the resource usage in CloudWatch. And if you see any bottlenecks you can increase resources. You can also make use of Autoscalling to automatically increase or decrease resources based on usage.

Answer (score 1):

t2.micro is EBS only

To see the memory use for the script that is specific to the script itself run it in a shell like this

```
FORMAT='%M' time myscript.py
```

This will give a memory use number in kB for the script.  The system itself also uses memory in the background, not all memory is available for running user programs like scripts