# How do I know if my EC2 instance is EBS-backed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do I know if my AWS EC2 instance is EBS-backed or not?

Our production EC2 instance has went down due to some hardware as per AWS:

> EC2 has detected degradation of the underlying hardware hosting your Amazon EC2 instance...  Due to this degradation your instance could already be unreachable. We will stop your instance after 2022-01-11 00:00:00 UTC. Please take appropriate action before this time.

I am trying to safely stop and start the EC2 instance so it goes on new underlying hardware without erasing the volumes we have on there. If I look under the Storage section, it does say the Root device type is EBS:

[storage-root-device-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khJeM.png)

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582584/how-to-tell-if-my-aws-ec2-instance-is-amazon-ebs-backed) but it wasn't clear to me for instances other than ones that say "EBS-only". As per this question's answer, I'm not sure if "AWS EC2 Root volume" means the same thing as Root device type = EBS under Storage>Root device details in the EC2 console.

Answer (score 1):

After going back and forth with AWS support, I can confirm that if under the Storage section, under Root device details, if it says **EBS** then the EC2 is indeed an **EBS-Backed instance**.

Additional context that I received from AWS and pasting here for others:

- EC2 instance which is EBS-backed (under root device details, it says EBS),  it would not be affected by stop-start because EBS volumes persist independently from the running life of an EC2 instance.
- It is recommended to take snapshot of the EBS volumes associated with an instance for backup purpose before Stop and Start of the Instance. [Link here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html)
- Whenever you receive an instance retirement notification, you can either wait for the scheduled retirement date - when the instance will be stopped through a automated workflow or you can stop the instance yourself before the retirement date and then you can start the instance again at any time. (We recommend the latter option i.e. to manually stop and start the instance).
- A start is required to migrate the instance to healthy hardware.

  - [Stop start instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#instance_stop)
  - [What happens when you Stop an instance?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html#instance_stop)
- In rare circumstances, the infrastructure-layer issue can prevent the underlying host from responding to the stop and start API calls. The instance may get stuck in the "stopping" state. In that case, you are presented with a "force stop" option. Kindly use force stop if you are not able to stop the instance if instance stuck in the "stopping" state.

#### What happens if system status checks were getting failed?

Please be informed that System status check failures indicate that there was an issue with the hardware hosting your EC2 instance. It is because of unhealthy underlying hardware due to which the instance became unresponsive and the instance needs to be migrated to a new, healthy host by stopping and starting the instance. System status checks monitor the AWS systems on which your instance runs. These checks detect underlying problems with your instance that require AWS involvement to repair. When a system status check fails, you can choose to wait for AWS to fix the issue, or you can resolve it yourself. For instances backed by Amazon EBS, you can stop and start the instance yourself, which in most cases results in the instance being migrated to a new host.

- The following are examples of problems that can cause system status checks to fail:

  - Loss of network connectivity
  - Loss of system power
  - Software issues on the physical host
  - Hardware issues on the physical host that impact network reachability

#### Why does instance become unreachable before the retirement date?

Because instance retirement is often the result of unexpected software or hardware failure, the underlying host can become inaccessible before the scheduled retirement date. AWS attempts to keep the instance accessible until the date provided, and in some cases can restore the host to working condition. The issue was pre-identified and there was a prior notification sent to you, but the hardware failure happened suddenly prior to the scheduled retirement. Our infrastructure is designed to be highly fault-tolerant, with multiple redundant systems available in case of any unforeseen issues. However, hardware and network failures are very hard to predict as electronics have a life-cycle.

***Disclaimer: this information is directly from AWS support and not my own. Posting here to help others get a faster answer directly from AWS support team***